# How do i start KX Developer

Tags: kdb

I have finished the installation, and follow this note

> If you added the alias output by the installer to your shell config file (eg. .bashrc or .bash_profile), simply open a terminal and type developer to start Developer.
>
> To start it manually, open a terminal and source the config file, then launch q and load the launcher.q_ file:

```
source /path-to-install-dir/config/config.profile
q /path-to-install-dir/launcher.q_
```

And i check /home/developer/config/config.profile file, open q add code

but i cant open KX Developer

error:
[image: error]

How do i do ?

How do i set .bashrc or bash_profile file?

thanks all

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Any follow up questions / issues that arise following the answers on your post should be an [edit] of your post or should be a  comment on the given answers instead of a new answer. This will confuse other readers and makes your post look a bit messy. If you are unsure about the styling, try reading how to [ask] and how to [answer] guides 

Comment: Perhaps better asked in [KX Community Developer Tools](https://community.kx.com/t5/Developer-Tools/bd-p/kdb-q-questions) forum.

Comment: Resolved @ https://community.kx.com/t5/Developer-Tools/I-can-t-start-KX-Developer-and-Pyq/td-p/13220

Answer (score 1):

Your paths should not be wrapped in `<>`

You want:

```
`DEVELOPER_HOME setenv "/home/evol/developer"
`DEVELOPER_DATA setenv "/home/evol/developer/data"
```